# iText check pdf integrity

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I want to validate relevant details of a pdf such as document hash signed, certificate validity and  any changes to document after signing.

To validate certificate, I can use pkcs7 to verify. However not sure how to validate document hash signed or compare the document hash in /Sig annotation and the original document?

PDFDictionary of type /Sig has /Type, /Filter, /SubFilter, /Reason, /ContactInfo, /M, /Name, /ByteRange and /Contents (which contains certificate data), can't find hash to be verified with.

Tried using several approaches around fetching PDFDictionary objects but couldn't find much.

Referred below link: [iText pdf integrity check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070029/itext-pdf-integrity-check)
but don't have a clarity on how to implement such thing in iText?

Comment: As you mention many more things you eventually want to do, one question: What you're asking now and here is how to calculate the PDF hash and validate that this calculated document hash is identical to the document hash in the signature?

Comment: Yes, to start with I think that should be the first step to check whether document has been altered or not. Any insights on how should I go about it?

Comment: You are aware that that essentially is what `SignatureUtil.readSignatureData` and `PdfPKCS7.verifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity` (iText 8.x) / `AcroFields.verifySignature` and `PdfPKCS7.verify` (iText 5.x) do? Should an answer here explain the use of those methods? Or do you want to independently implement a similar functionality?